# Grails - Iterating over a map from service into csv file - Groovy

Tags: csv, grails, groovy

How can I iterate over the result map into CSV file?
I can iterate them fine when I have my method in the controller block but if I put it in the service and call, it doesn't recognize the key and returns empty rows. ( it.column_1 is not recognized.)

```
class someController {
    def someService

    def export(Person personInstance) {
        def resultRows = someService.result(personInstance)

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.csv")
        response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        def outs = response.outputStream

        outs << "${personInstance}\n"
        outs << "Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4\n"

        resultRows.each() { 
            outs << it.column_1 + "," + it.column_2 + "," + it.column_3 + "," + it.column_4
            outs << "\n"
        }
        outs.flush()
        outs.close()
    }       
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I've included the code that works.

When I println resultRows right after someService.result to the console I get

[[column_1:John,column_2:Doe,column_3:123 Main Street,column_4:(123)456-7890][column_1:John,column_2:Doe,column_3:123 Main Street,column_4:(123)456-7890]]

With the following code I get a downloadable CSV file in excel format.

```
class someController {

    def export(Person personInstance) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def resultRows = sql.rows('select * from table where person_id = ?', [personInstance.id])

        [resultRows:resultRows]

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.csv")
        response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        def outs = response.outputStream

        outs << "${personInstance}\n"
        outs << "Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4\n"

        resultRows.each() { 
            outs << it.column_1 + "," + it.column_2 + "," + it.column_3 + "," + it.column_4
            outs << "\n"
        }
        outs.flush()
        outs.close()
    }       
}
```

**EDIT - FOUND ANSWER**

Ah, I figured out the problem. I had [resultRows:resultRows] inside the service. I deleted that line and put it in the controller right under def resultRows row.

```
def export(Person personInstance) {
    def resultRows = someService.result(personInstance)
    [resultRows:resultRows]
....
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Please show the code that produces the error **it.column_1 is not recognized**.

Comment: Is there a typo? 'resultRows.each() {  code'... should it be 'resultRows.each { code '   ?

Comment: @jayan they're the same thing, but you're right, your way is much more idiomatic groovy :-)

Comment: What does `someService.result` return? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @ tim_yates : thanks.

Comment: Please show the code that works fine and the one that doesn't.

Comment: @tim-yates I have included the code that works.

Comment: I normally wouldn't recommend this, but have you tried disabling transactions on the `someService.result(Person)` method? I've never used `Sql` objects with Grails, but maybe it's conflicting with gorm transactions.

Comment: It shouldn't effect whether you are executing the sql.rows() inside a service or controller. As you have posted yourself, the o/p of resultRows right after someService.result, its a List<Map>. So shouldn't face any issues while iterating over a list and accessing each entry from its map element. Please post the exception that you are getting.

Comment: @Sandeep Poonia, It doesn't give me an exception. When I click export button, there is no data under the Column Header. But when I execute the sql.rows in the controller and export, I see the rows of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I figured out the problem. I had [resultRows:resultRows] inside the service. I deleted that line and put it in the controller right under def resultRows row.

```
def export(Person personInstance) {
    def resultRows = someService.result(personInstance)
    [resultRows:resultRows]
....
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer on your own question. If you find a solution, you can edit your question and put it in there.

Comment: @BearArmatis, Quite the contrary. The StackOverflow explicitly encourages answering your own question when you have a right answer. Here is the link to the FAQ.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment.  I honestly did not know that.

Comment: Given you up vote here and on another question. You now have 50 hopefully can comment now

Comment: @vahid, Thanks. You're kind.